# Ignore specific lines when matching with a regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a regex that matches a specific pattern, but I want to ignore lines starting with a `#`. How do I do it?

Let's say i have the pattern `(?i)(^|\W)[a-z]($|\W)`

It matches all lines with a single occurance of a letter. It matches these lines for instance:

```
asdf e asdf
j
kke o
```

Now I want to override this so that it does not match lines starting with a `#`

EDIT:

I was not specific enough. My real pattern is more complicated. It looks a bit like this: (?i)(^|\W)([a-hj-z]|lala|bwaaa|foo($|\W)

It should be used kind of like I want to block offensive language, if a line does not start with a hash, in which case it should override.

Answer (score 9):

This is what you are looking for

```
^(?!#).+$
```

`^` marks the beginning of line and `$` marks the end of line (in multiline mode)

`.+` would match 1 to many characters

`(?!#)` is a lookahead which would match further only if the line doesn't start with `#`

Answer (score 1):

This regex will match any word character `\w` not preceeded by a `#`:

```
^(?<!#)\w+$
```

It performs a negative lookbehind at the start of the string and then follows it with 1 or more word characters.

Comment: it should be `lookahead` not `lookbehind`..also with `\w` you would match only words!